# More padding was added on logo jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was trying to perfect my jQuery submenu but I stumble w/ some CSS issues.

Here are my questions:

1. How can I fix the issue when I re-open the navigation again it adds more padding on the bottom than it was opened for the first time?

```css
.sidebar-nav {
  position: fixed;
  float: left;
  width: 250px;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #e74c3c;
  color: #aaabae;
  font-family: "Lato";
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  z-index: 1;
}

#nav {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#nav li {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  padding: 0;
}

#nav li ul {
  opacity: 0;
  height: 0px;
}

#nav li a {
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 16px 25px;
  color: #fff;
  white-space: nowrap;
  z-index: 2;
  text-decoration: none
}

#nav li a:hover {
  color: #c0392b;
  background-color: #ecf0f1;
}



#nav ul li { 
 background-color: #2b303a; 
}

#nav li:first-child { 
 border-top: 1px solid #fff;
}

#nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}



#nav .fa { margin: 0px 17px 0px 0px; }

.logo {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 21px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#logo{
color: #fff;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-style: normal;
}

.sidebar-icon {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1;
  font-size: 25px;
  padding: 6px 8px;
  color: #fff;
}

.disp {
  opacity: 1!important;
  height:auto!important;
   transition: height 100ms ease-in-out;
  transition-delay: 300ms;
}
```

Comment: 1. It may be you can format your question properly in via [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36587006/edit)? 2. post [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), so we can work with your code and to help you out quicker.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
html,
body {
 font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  height: 100%;
  background: #ecf0f1;
}


a {
  color: #008DE7;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 700;
}


.content {
  min-width: 1260px;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

.content.sidebar-collapsed {
  padding-right: 65px;
  transition: all 100ms linear;
  transition-delay: 300ms;
}

.content.sidebar-collapsed-back {
  padding-right: 280px;
  transition: all 100ms linear;
}

.content.sidebar-collapsed .sidebar-nav {
  width: 65px;
  transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;
  transition-delay: 300ms;
}

.content.sidebar-collapsed-back .sidebar-nav {
  width: 280px;
  transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;
}

.content.sidebar-collapsed .logo {
  padding: 18px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;
  transition-delay: 300ms;
  padding-bottom:0;
  margin:0;
}

.content.sidebar-collapsed-back .logo {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 21px;
  /* height: 136px; */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;
}

.content.sidebar-collapsed #logo {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
}

.content.sidebar-collapsed-back #logo {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
  transition-delay: 300ms;
}

.content.sidebar-collapsed #nav span {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 50ms linear;
}

.content.sidebar-collapsed-back #nav span {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 200ms linear;
}

.sidebar-nav {
  position: fixed;
  float: left;
  width: 250px;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #e74c3c;
  color: #aaabae;
  font-family: "Lato";
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  z-index: 1;
}

#nav {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#nav li {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  padding: 0;
}

#nav li ul {
  opacity: 0;
  height: 0px;
}

#nav li a {
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 16px 25px;
  color: #fff;
  white-space: nowrap;
  z-index: 2;
  text-decoration: none
}

#nav li a:hover {
  color: #c0392b;
  background-color: #ecf0f1;
}



#nav ul li { 
    background-color: #2b303a; 
}

#nav li:first-child { 
    border-top: 1px solid #fff;
}

#nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}



#nav .fa { margin: 0px 17px 0px 0px; }

.logo {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 21px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#logo{
color: #fff;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-style: normal;
}

.sidebar-icon {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1;
  font-size: 25px;
  padding: 6px 8px;
  color: #fff;
}

.disp {
  opacity: 1!important;
  height:auto!important;
   transition: height 100ms ease-in-out;
  transition-delay: 300ms;
}
```

[demo:](http://jsfiddle.net/q4nnzu7h/1/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. DO YOU KNOW HOW TO SIMPLIFY MY JQUERY CODES?

Comment: please accept this answer and the previous question answer

Answer (score 1):

I modified the margins as some elements have some inncorrect margins and I made some modifications to the transitions as well, also I modified the navigation's width as it starts as 250px and become 280px after collapsing and expanding again.

just try this, hope it helps :)

```
html,
body {
 font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  height: 100%;
  background: #ecf0f1;
}


a {
  color: #008DE7;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 700;
}


.content {
  min-width: 1260px;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

.content.sidebar-collapsed {
  padding-right: 65px;
  transition: all 100ms linear;
  transition-delay: 300ms;
}

.content.sidebar-collapsed-back {
  padding-right: 280px;
}

.content.sidebar-collapsed .sidebar-nav {
  width: 65px;
  transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;
  transition-delay: 300ms;
}

.content.sidebar-collapsed-back .sidebar-nav {
  width: 250px;
}

.content.sidebar-collapsed .logo {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: all 200ms;
  overflow:auto;
}

.content.sidebar-collapsed-back .logo {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 21px;
  margin:0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.content.sidebar-collapsed #logo {
  opacity: 0;
  display:none;
  transition: all 200ms;
}

.content.sidebar-collapsed-back #logo {
  opacity: 1;
  display:inline-block;
  transition-delay:500ms;
}

.content.sidebar-collapsed #nav span {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 200ms;
}

.content.sidebar-collapsed-back #nav .fa-plus {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 200ms;
}

.content.sidebar-collapsed-back #nav .fa-plus {
  opacity: 1;
  transition-delay:500ms;
}

.content.sidebar-collapsed-back #nav span {
  opacity: 1;
}

.sidebar-nav {
  position: fixed;
  float: left;
  width: 250px;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #e74c3c;
  color: #aaabae;
  font-family: "Lato";
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  z-index: 1;
  transition:all 200ms;
}

#nav {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#nav li {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  padding: 0;
}

#nav li ul {
  opacity: 0;
  height: 0px;
  transition:all 200ms;
}

#nav li a {
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 16px 25px;
  color: #fff;
  white-space: nowrap;
  z-index: 2;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#nav li a:hover {
  color: #c0392b;
  background-color: #ecf0f1;
}



#nav ul li { 
    background-color: #2b303a; 
}

#nav li:first-child { 
    border-top: 1px solid #fff;
}

#nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}



#nav .fa { margin: 0px 17px 0px 0px; }

.logo {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 21px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#logo{
color: #fff;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-style: normal;
}

.sidebar-icon {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1;
  font-size: 25px;
  height:34px;
  color: #fff;
}

.disp {
  opacity: 1!important;
  height:auto!important;
   transition:all 200ms;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Ensure that the `height` property of `.logo` is set to the same value when `.content` is both with and without the `.sidebar-collapsed` class.
2. The `padding` property of `.logo` is too large; there is barely any room left for the hamburger.

It seems you are only using `padding` to center the other menu icons. Consider another tactic - there are plenty of better ways to do it.

- https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/#center-horizontally
- http://howtocenterincss.com/